# TypeScript compiler fails to eliminate filtered types from union typed argument

Tags: typescript

I ran into a problem with the TypeScript compiler and would appreciate any help people might be able to offer.

I have reduced the issue original code as much as possible, and I believe the source of the issue is coming from the second `if` statement.

```
// This code generates a compile error.

let val: boolean;

function foo(bar: string | string[] | boolean, qux: string[]): void {
    if ('boolean' === typeof bar) {
        val = bar;
        // At this point TypeScript correctly knows the type of bar is `boolean`
        return;
    }
    // At this point TypeScript correctly knows the type of bar is `string | string[]`

    if (!Array.isArray(bar)) {
        // Here the compiler understand that `bar` can only be a `string`

        bar = [bar];
        // This is where things start getting wonky.
        //
        // Here the compiler thinks `bar` is of type `string | string[] | boolean`
        // We have eliminated `boolean` already. We also know that `bar` is not an array because we are 
        // inside this `if` block.
    }
    // At this point TypeScript correctly knows the type of bar is `string[]`

    val = qux.every(q => bar.includes(q)); // Here the compiler fails.
    // semantic error TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'false'.
}
```

Interestingly, by simply changing the structure of the function the compiler becomes happy again. In this function we exit early and return a value instead. The type checks are identical, but because we return the values the type is correctly understood by the compiler.

```
// This code compiles just fine.

function foo(bar: string | string[] | boolean, qux: string[]): boolean {
    if ('boolean' === typeof bar) {
        return bar;
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(bar)) {
        return qux.includes(bar);
    }
    return bar.every(b => qux.includes(b));
}
```

So after all that, my question is why does both `bar = [bar];` and `val = qux.every(q => bar.includes(q));` have a different (erroneous) type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat of a puzzle, because on the face of it, Typescript is wrong to give `bar` the weaker type in the lambda, and in this *specific* code there is no unsafe behaviour.

However, *in the general case*, Typescript is correct to give `bar` the weaker type within the lambda even though `bar` has the stronger type on the same line as it is used in the lambda. The issue can be demonstrated by the code below:

```
function demo(x: string | number) {
    if(typeof x === 'number') {
        x = 'now x is a string';
    }

    // type is string here, so no error
    x.includes('now');

    // type is string | number here, so this is an error
    let f: Function = () => x.includes('now');

    x = 23;

    // type is number here
    f();
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYFs4AoAeAuRAZygCcYwBzRAH0TBHQCNUSBKRAbwChFfEZgWKAE8ADqjjBEORAF55iAOT0mLRe258t0uUrBwA7jpiFEAQyKlyFRQG4efAL5cHvAPRvEI8f1PEylIgAFiyoADREcHRRLCRwJK7SAHTkEAA2IGiEWMqG6vaJHl5iqL6WAVS0KswkwaERhFFQQSZlZkix8YlpqFCIwAQAYuDQ8EiyiFjssgB8yakZWTn6BvkuWjITAEwAzAVaRd6lrdUsdSSoiYKs9s5AA)

This code is not type-safe, because although `x` does have type `string` where the function is declared, `x` actually has the type `number` where the function is called; so there is no `includes` method. Typescript is therefore right to complain about the code. But this code has the same structure as yours; you used a variable in a lambda, and Typescript does not know the lambda will not be called when that variable later has a different type, so *in the lambda's scope* the variable has the weaker type.

In theory, Typescript *could* be designed to know that an array's `every` method calls the lambda immediately and then discards it, so that in your specific code the variable is definitely going to be a string each time the lambda is called. However, Typescript's type system is not powerful enough to know what circumstances a lambda will be called in, and it would have to be rather more complicated if it did.

Your second example has no error because your lambda calls `qux.includes` inside the lambda, instead of `bar.includes`. Since the variable `qux` always has type `string[]`, and was not narrowed from a weaker type, this cannot cause a problem.

Comment: Very interesting! The only thing I still don't understand is what is up with the `bar = [bar];`.

Comment: @DanielMorell That's just a quirk of how it's displayed; immediately after `bar = [bar];`, the variable `bar` does correctly have type `string`, it just doesn't show in IntelliSense if you hover over `bar` on *that* line. But if you write `bar` on the next line, it shows as `string`. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUAjAhgJwFyIDOUOMYA5ogD5ElnkDaAugJQEBucMAJogN4AoRMMQxgiNAEIAgjhxYAngDoYhWfIWZcLFvyEiDAekOjxCuCEQALOOwCmORFCurEAGzJ2ANKKhFFhIgABsSkFNS0YYxMQV76BsLYjgC8iAxJTADcAvEJxogYIH5WDna+iBBwcnbQbgr+CoEhdBRBSrkGSbkAvgLdQA)

Comment: Hmm... I am using WebStorm and if I put `bar` on the next line I get `string | string[] | boolean`. So that must be an issue with WebStorm.

Comment: I'm surprised there is a difference, since both should be getting the information from the same source (i.e. the Typescript [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) implementation). I don't use WebStorm, so I'm afraid I can't investigate further.